# Entity Framework Relationship Error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I get the following error when using Entity Framework:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types
'xxx.Domain.Entities.UserSettings' and 'xxx.Domain.Entities.User'. The 
principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either 
the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Here are the two Entity classes:

```
public class User
{
    [Key, Column("un")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public virtual UserSettings UserSettings { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int ActiveRefresh { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Username")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error. I am stuck with the database design so I can't update that to fix the issue. Is there a way using Fluent Api to get these associations working?

A User can have a UserSettings object. This is the relationship that is desired.

Comment: just a thought: "User" in `ForeignKey("User")` does not seem to match something?

Comment: What type of relationship to you want between these two entities? And yes, Fluent Api can do all that annotations can and more. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)

Comment: @PeterSmith A User can have a UserSettings object. This is the relationship that is desired. The current setup is confusing EntityFramework. I updated the question with this as well.

Comment: I believe that your `[ForeignKey]` attribute should be on the foreign key property, not on the related object. It's trying to determine how an object is the relationship specifier between the two classes.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I updated the title but the context text of "Entity Framework" is necessary in my opinion.

Comment: @CamilleSévigny absolutely, but this is no tagging like before ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a one to zero-or-one relationship

```
// Configure the primary key for the User
modelBuilder.Entity<User>() 
    .HasKey(t => t.Username); 

// Map one-to-zero or one relationship 
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSettings>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.User) 
    .WithOptional(t => t.UserSettings);
```

This is not tested! Remove all the annotations from the entity classes. The link to [Fluent API relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620) in my comment above has more examples of the different kinds of relationship.

Comment: This was what I ended up using. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

using anotations :

```
public class User
{
    [Key, Column("un")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    //here is your foreign to UserSettings
    public int? UserSettingsID{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserSettingsID")] // not needed if you're using the '%ID' convention
    //Navigation property
    public virtual UserSettings UserSettings { get; set; }
}

public class UserSettings
{
    //UserSettings PK
    public int UserSettingsID{ get; set; }
    public int ActiveRefresh { get; set; }
}
```

I assume here that you don't need to retrieve the user from his settings